# How is net run rate calculated if one team loses overs due to a penalty?

Tags: cricket, icc, cricket-world-cup

My question is based on cricket NRR calculation. Below is the scenario explained:

1. Match start time 7:45am, date 13-08-2017, match overs 16 decided by organizer.
2. Match between team A and team B
3. Team A had time delay and penalty of 1 overs reduction was announced by organizer
4. Team B played complete 16 overs, whereas team A played only 15 overs

Question: The run rate for Team A should be calculated considering 15 overs or 16 overs?

Comment: Do you have a link to the regulations for the competetion as they will say what should happen in this case.  I would suspect there part of NRR would be calculated using 15 overs.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, total 16 overs will be counted on both the side, overs played by team a will be 16 overs and overs bowled by team b will be 16 overs, but on the ground team a will only get to play 15 overs.

Answer (score 0):

The run rate should always be calculated according to the actual number of overs involved. NRR will be calculated by number of overs batted (not how many were allocated at the start), RRR will be calculated by number of overs remaining (not how many would have been remaining if there were no reductions).

This means too that if a team is bowled out in fewer overs than the innings allowed, the NRR will be calculated by how long they batted, not how long they *could* have batted.

However, I'm sure it's possible to have a tournament with playing conditions which stipulate a different NRR calculation for statistical purposes. Can't really think why, but it's possible. You should check the tourname PQs to make sure there's no such clause.

Comment: Are you able to provide references to support this answer? In particular, the [playing conditions for the T20 World Cup](https://icc-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2020/02/18/a25f5c1d-2990-4c6e-9287-9b2343af51f8/ICC-Women-s-T20-World-Cup-Playing-Conditions-18-Feb-2020-clean.pdf) make clear in 16.10.6 that NRR counts the full quota of overs in the case of a team being dismissed in fewer than its full quota.